# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing [PYTHON,BS4]

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm just a beginner in python or programming in general, because of my lacking knowledge pretty vulnerable to mysterious syntax errors. Of course, I tried to find a solution, but after endless googling, I only know that a method was potentially not closed. Perhaps someone who knows will find the mistake?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv

a=0
genre=[]


def Extraction():   
  a=0 
  with open('Unbenannt 1.csv','r') as csv_file:
      c = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
      karten=[]
      for row in c:
          karten.append(row['Name'])
          genre.append(row['Genre'])
          karten[a]=karten[a].replace(" ", "-")
          print(karten[a]) #approved
          print(genre[a])  #approved
          a+=1
      return karten

def spezFunction(test):
  UClient = uReq(test)
  pageRawHTML = UClient.read()
  UClient.close()

  psoup = soup(pageRawHTML,"html.parser")

  namen=psoup.find_all('div',{"class":"flex-grow-1"})
  print(namen[0].h1.text)

  preis=psoup.find_all('dd',{"class":"col-6 col-xl-7"})
  print('Durchschnitt: ' + preis[6].span.text)
  verf=preis[3].text
  print('Anzahl: ' + verf)
  einzel=preis[8].text
  print('Einzelpreis: ' + einzel)

def MyUrl():
  karten=Extraction()
  print(karten[0])
  a=0
  url=[]
  for elements in karten:
      url.append('https://www.cardmarket.com/de/' + genre[a]+ '/Products/Search?searchString=' + karten[a])
      a+=1
      
  return url
  

spezFunction((MyUrl()[1])
```

You see the function extraction works with a static URL pretty well, but since I introduced the MyUrl function, the EOF starts.

Comment: Post traceback at nekobin.com / any other website please.

Comment: Post the full traceback as part of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line of your code i.e `spezFunction((MyUrl()[1])` should be - `spezFunction((MyUrl()[1]))`

You were missing one right parenthesis :)

Comment: @Axerox if you found my answer helpful  please consider to upvote and accept it.